# Start/stop image view rotation animations

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a start/stop button and an image view which I want to rotate.

When I press the button I want the to start rotating and when I press the button again the image should stop rotating. I am currently using an `UIView` animation, but I haven't figured out a way to stop the view animations.

I want the image to rotate, but when the animation stops the image shouldn't go back to the starting position, but instead continue the animation.

```
var isTapped = true

    @IBAction func startStopButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
       ruotate()
       isTapped = !isTapped
    }

    func ruotate() {
        if isTapped {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.imageWood.transform =     self.imageWood.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            }, completion: { finished in
            ruotate()
            })
    }  }
```

It is my code, but it doesn't work like I aspect.

Comment: You could use `CABasicAnimation` for achieving the start/stop animation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Swift 3.x**

**Start Animation**

```
let rotationAnimation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: .pi * 2.0)
    rotationAnimation.duration = 0.5;
    rotationAnimation.isCumulative = true;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity;
    self.imageWood?.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
```

**Stop animation**

```
self.imageWood?.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "rotationAnimation")
```

**Swift 2.x**

**Start Animation**

```
let rotationAnimation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(double: M_PI * 2.0)
    rotationAnimation.duration = 1;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = true;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity;
    self.imageWood?.layer.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
```

**Stop animation**

```
self.imageWood?.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "rotationAnimation")
```

Comment: That will stop the animation as you say, but the layer will snap to it's final position. If you want it to stop the animation at it's current state, you need to take extra steps: One option might be to fetch the layer's transform from the presentation layer, set that transform on the actual layer, and then remove the animation. Another option would be to set the animation speed on the animation to zero.

Comment: @DuncanC thanks for your suggestion, also I am inviting you to edit the answer with another way..!!

Comment: I just posted an answer with an alternate solution.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `UIView` Animation the OS still creates one or more `CAAnimation` objects. Thus, to stop a UIView animation you can still use:

```
myView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Or if you create the animation using a CAAnimation on a layer:

```
myLayer.removeAllAnimations()
```

In either case, you can capture the current state of the animation and set that as the final state before removing the animation. If you're doing an animation on a view's transform, like in this question, that code might look like this:

```
func stopAnimationForView(_ myView: UIView) {

  //Get the current transform from the layer's presentation layer
  //(The presentation layer has the state of the "in flight" animation)
  let transform = myView.layer.presentationLayer.transform

  //Set the layer's transform to the current state of the transform
  //from the "in-flight" animation
  myView.layer.transform = transform

  //Now remove the animation 
  //and the view's layer will keep the current rotation
  myView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
}
```

If you're animating a property other than the transform you'd need to change the code above.

Comment: This is perfect but if i want start from again from last paused state its not working...

Comment: @SaifanNadaf, see my other answer to this question using UIViewPropertyAnimator. This answer destroys the animation, making it impossible to resume it. The other answer allows you to pause and resume animations. It's also possible to pause and resume a CAAnimation "manually" but it's tricky and hard to figure out UIViewPropertyAnimator is much easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

using your existing code you can achieve it the following way

```
    var isTapped = true

@IBAction func startStopButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    ruotate()
    isTapped = !isTapped
}

func ruotate() {
    if isTapped {
        let rotationAnimation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotationAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: Double.pi * 2.0)
        rotationAnimation.duration = 1;
        rotationAnimation.isCumulative = true;
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE;
        self.imageWood?.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }else{
        self.imageWood?.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a wild repeat count

Answer (score 2):

Apple added a new class, `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, to iOS 10. A `UIViewPropertyAnimator` allows you to easily create UIView-based animations that can be paused, reversed, and scrubbed back and forth.

If you refactor your code to use a A `UIViewPropertyAnimator` you should be able to pause and resume your animation.

I have a [**sample project on Github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/UIViewPropertyAnimator-test) that demonstrates using a `UIViewPropertyAnimator`. I suggest taking a look at that.

Comment: Thanks Duncan. I am looking to support iOS 9+ so that may probably be a second option as of now.

Comment: Plus, I've found your library, although quite remarkable, a little bit complex to adapt to my project. I don't know where I would I implement the rotation logic into the view controller. I understand that there is a `viewAnimator`, but don't how everything would come into play.

Comment: See my second answer. That shows how to stop an animation and have it freeze at it's current state.

Answer (score 1):

Your code make the image rotate for 2PI angle, but if you click on the button while the rotation is not ended, the animation will finish before stop, that's why it comes to the initial position.

You should use [CABasicAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation) to use a rotation that you can stop at anytime keeping the last position.